# How to select count(distinct) with condition inside groups

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

The SQL I want is something like this:

```
SELECT week_no, type,
 SELECT count(distinct user_id) FROM group WHERE pts > 0
FROM base_table
GROUP BY week_no, type
```

But I know I can use `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` to count the total number of users in each group, but how can I count the number of users who meet the condition 'pts > 0'?

I'm using mysql,

Thanks.

Comment: The base_table could be larger than 14GB

Comment: Why wouldn't a where clause `where where pts >0`?  Do you need to list all week_no and types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT week_no, type, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pts > 0 THEN user_id END)
FROM base_table
GROUP BY week_no, type;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1d1a/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: It seems mysql doesn't support that?

Comment: @qin.sun Odd, demo works as it should. Please share error message

Comment: @lad2015 I find you right! I just refer to this page(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) and use 'END CASE' to end my case, after I remove the 'CASE', it's OK, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

the condition for group is made with "having" clause

SELECT count(user_id) FROM group group by user_id having pts > 0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT week_no, type, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id )
FROM base_table
where pts > 0
GROUP BY week_no, type
```

Filter userid's in where clause instead.

Comment: Spot the difference **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d255d/2/1)**. You may exclude some weeks and types

Comment: i am filtering rows before group by clause and in your case you are filtering rows after group by clause.

Comment: I know, but you exclude data instead of set 0. See that OP uses subquery in his question. Of course as always it depends on requirements.

Comment: instead of counting it for each group i have done it once.

Comment: You still count it for each group. COUNT works per group not entire resultset. The only thing that change is expression column vs CASE.

Comment: And exclude group `2` yes I know it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, but the example above is just a part of my query, I still need those rows with pts == 0. Sorry for the ambiguity, and thank you again:D